Merge conflicts in Azure DevOps pipeline using Bitbucket
Is there a way to use Azure DevOps pipeline to be triggered by a Bitbucket tag/commit and use git commands inside ‘script’ steps to pull and merge another branch of Bitbucket?
We are getting the pipeline to run but it’s using a detached HEAD branch and we’re getting merge conflicts when trying to use a ‘git pull origin develop’ command
- job: merge_and_build
  pool:
    vmImage: ubunto-latest
    
    - script: |
        git checkout new-branch
        git pull origin develop

The output for the pipeline step
Auto-merging <file1>
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in <file1>
Auto-merging <file2>
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in <file2>
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and the commit the result.

Try using git commands and expecting a git pull origin develop to merge branches
